# Loading a jQuery plugin with CommonJS

Tags: javascript, commonjs, webpack

I'm trying to use Webpack to bring in JS modules, including jQuery and a jQuery plugin. I can load jQuery in without any problem, but when I try to load in a plugin to use along with it, I get a `jQuery is not defined` error in my browser console. I'm pretty new to Common JS and Webpack so any help would be really appreciated.

Here's my code so far:

```
var $ = require('../../../../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js');
require('../../../../../bower_components/jquery.uniform/jquery.uniform.js');

module.exports = function(){
    function init(){
        $('select, checkbox').uniform();
    }

    return {
        init: init
    };
}();
```

It's at the end of the `jquery.uniform.js` file that I get the error I mentioned above, because it references `jQuery`, which for some reason is not yet defined.

```
(function (wind, $, undef) {
    ...
    ...
}(this, jQuery));
```

Any ideas how to make this work? Or am I doing this completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to give it a go through npm. Set up a `package.json` dep like this:

```
"uniform": "pixelmatrix/uniform#v2.1.2",
```

Also make sure `jquery` is within your project (ie. `npm i jquery --save`).

After these steps you could try an import like this:

```
var uniform = require('imports?$=jquery!uniform/jquery.uniform');
```

You should be able to push the nasty looking import to Webpack configuration provided this works. I hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting. Is there really any need for Bower if I go this route? Or does npm essentially take over the role of Bower? That probably makes things a lot simpler if the answer is yes

Comment: Yeah, often you can just use npm instead. It tends to work well with Webpack although you may need to shim things a bit every once in a while.